# To read MS Access 2010 mdb files with VB6 do I need to get an updated a driver?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2010

I am writing a VB6 program that needs to open an MS Access 2010 database (.mdb) but I get an "invalid file type" error when I try.  Do I need to get updated driver(s)?

Comment: If you can open the Access database with your development machine then you should be able to open it through code. You are not showing any code so we are unable to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I needed but did not know it was "install VB6 SP6".  I had installed VB6 on a new PC a couple of years ago, and was not aware of the service pack to let VB6 handle post MS Access 1997 tables.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you the same Dale who asked the question? Did you happen to create two accounts? If yes, [please have them merged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)!